# TinyMCE Rich text editor does not allow multiple text editors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am using TinyMCE Rich text Editor in my MVC app. I am using tinymce.js and tinymce.min.js.
The problem that I am facing is that I am not able to show multiple rich text editors in my app.
If the user is chose to have one editor, then it is working fine but if more than one selection is made then editor is showing up only for the first one and rest comes up as normal text areas.

Please help.

Snippets of my code:

Bundle containing TinyMCE:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tinymce")
```

Global.asax:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            //Creating bundle for your js files
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/tinymce").Include(
            "~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"));
        }
```

There is no browser script error. JSScript error comes up  saying: 
**"Object doesn't support this property or method" error"**

`Tiny_Mcefull.cshtml` now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){ 

        tinyMCE.init({

            // General options
            mode: "exact",
            elements: "@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)",
            theme: "advanced",
            height: "500",
            width: "790",
            verify_html : false,
            plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,codehighlighting,netadvimage",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : false,

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            //content_css : "css/content.css",
            content_css : '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/css/content.css")',
            convert_urls : false,

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js"

        });

    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of View where you try to init 2 tinyMCE?
Once i had this problem. Reason was that i try to init Tiny MCE twice.

Comment: Hi teo, do you want me to provide you with tinymce_full.cshtml codE?

Comment: You get package from Nuget and change nothing in it?

Comment: Yea I did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tinymce")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqgrid")
</head>
```

Can't say right now why, but i remember that it was important to plug TinyMCE after Jquery.
TinyMCE Template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){ 

        tinyMCE.init({

            // General options
            mode: "exact",
            elements: "@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)",
            theme: "advanced",
            height: "500",
            width: "790",
            verify_html : false,
            plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,codehighlighting,netadvimage",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : false,

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            //content_css : "css/content.css",
            content_css : "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/css/content.css")",
            convert_urls : false,

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        });

    })();

</script>

@Html.TextArea(string.Empty, /* Name suffix */
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue /* Initial value */
)
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Thank you so much Teo, let me try with the answer provided by you.

Comment: I am still not able to get multiple editors.I am getting an JScript error saying object doesn't support this property, with an error in getting the theme. :(

Comment: Can you provide your View code where you try to creating it? And Browser sripts errors if they exist?

Comment: I have added snippets in the question

Comment: Sorry, but i still don't see full picture.

Which bundle contains TinyMCE script now?

How `tinymce_full.cshtml` looks now after changing?

Can you post Brouser script full error?

Comment: sad but it is still not working for me :(
I am still getting Jscript error.

Comment: to understad problem, i still need more info... Easiest way - project to github =) Or lines with errors to post.